# Group by clause is not working properly in my query

Tags: php, mysql, join

first table : "wp_pc_products"

```
feed_product_name   feed_product_image   price   deeplink    id_merchant
sony xperia c3      abc.png              12000   abc.html     fkt
sony xperia         xyz.png              11000   aaa.html     snd
sony xperia M       pqr.png              10000   bbb.html     fkt
```

second table: "wp_pc_products_merchants"

```
slug     image
fkt      logo1.png
snd      logo2.png
```

My existing query

```
 select p.feed_product_name,p.feed_product_image,p.price,p.deeplink,p.id_merchant,m.image 
 from wp_pc_products p
 JOIN wp_pc_products_merchants m ON m.slug=p.id_merchant
 and (feed_product_name like'%sony%' or feed_product_name like'%xperia%' 
 or feed_product_name like'%c3%' ) and price BETWEEN "11829.3" and "21968.7"
```

result O/P

```
feed_product_name   feed_product_image  price  deeplink  id_merchant   image
sony xperia c3      abc.png             12000   abc.html   fkt         logo1.png
sony xperia         xyz.png             11000   aaa.html   snd         logo2.png
sony xperia M       pqr.png             10000   bbb.html   fkt         logo1.png
```

By using above join query i got the output that i require, but look at the image column in O/P.
As per my query "logo1.png" is repeated two times instead of that i want to show only first two records only, for that i use group by clause in above query but when i use group by the query doesn't show me any output. please tell me on which column i use group by clause in above query.
please suggest me the best.

Comment: show how did you use `group by`

Comment: Two products "sony xperia c3" and "sony xperia M" are with the same id_merchant, which is why "log1.png" is repeated.

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest    I use group by at the end of query-> "group by id_merchant" because of this i can't able to retrive records, may be query gets wrong, so on which column i use group by clause

Comment: @Dylan Su -> you are telling absolutely right both product have same id_merchant, that is why image is repeated, but how i can't able to repeat that one that is my query.

Comment: So your desired output is one row per image? And with each you want to show one of the related product records? Which one? Which wp_pc_products record do you want to show for logo1.png and why? Strange table names by the way; one table contains a product and merchant but is only called products; the other is named products_merchants and contains only merchant images. You might want to change this for readability and maintenability reasons.

Comment: Is slug unique in wp_pc_products_merchants or can there be more than one image per merchant? If there can be more: Do you want one result row per merchant or one row per image?

Comment: The matched related product  is fetched in my desire output, and as per image i want individual related matched products(can't repeat image).The sulg and image is unique in a table wp_pc_products_merchant

Comment: Which means the *combination of the two* is unique and I can have several images for one merchant? And several merchants sharing one image?

Comment: Anyway, what you are reporting here is strange. Your query retrieves three rows, but when you add `group by id_merchant` you are getting no error and no rows? MySQL should produce two rows, one for each merchant. The values for merchant fkt would be arbitrarily chosen by the DBMS, so you get either 'abc.png' or 'pqr.png', either 12000 or 10000, etc. But it should retrieve rows, I see no reason for this to fail. Maybe a typo? Try it once more please.

Comment: ya it take either abc.png or pqr.png ->but when i add group by id_merchant i am not getting any error and also not getting any products also

Comment: Ohh! it's run properly by using group by, Thank you very much

Comment: can i use LIMIT in above query, when i use in the end of query it's not working, suggest me

Comment: waiting for your reply